# Parallelize function evaluation with different parameters

Tags: functions, parallelization

How do you **run the same function multiple times and at the same time, but with different parameters**?

I have had a look at `ParallelEvaluate[]` but it is meant to run the same function multiple times but with the same parameters.

For instance: 
I have the following function: `f[x_]: = a*x+b*x`
Now I would like to run this function on multiple kernels at the same time with different parameters for `a` and `b`...

pseudocode:

```
(*Define function in current notebook with default kernel*)    
f[x_]: = a*x+b*x

RunParallel[{ (*pseudocode*)
{a=1,b=1,f[1]}, (*send to kernel1*)
{a=2,b=2,f[1]}, (*send to kernel2*)
{a=3,b=3,f[1]}, (*send to kernel3*)
{a=4,b=4,f[1]}  (*send to kernel4*)
}]
```

Comment: How about including the parameters to the arguments of the function? This way, the definitions would localized. Much more robust and debuggable coding style.

Comment: Alternatively, you may use something like `Block[{a=1,b=1},f[x]]`...

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher The syntax of `ParallelEvaluate` doesn't permit to call in parallel the same function with different agruments (say f[1] and f[2] in parallel).I think the only way to launch the same function with different parameters with`ParallelEvaluate` is to use a shared variable (or some `Random..` in the kernels).

Comment: @andre thanks for the comment. Would you mind to explain in more details how to do it? I am just beginning to get to know parallel evaluation.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I agree, but I cannot change the function's input parameter, unfortunately.

Comment: The problem is also with your "function". The definition should read `f[x_]: = a*x+b*x` (with underscore to turn the first `x` into a pattern.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher thanks, that was simply a misspelling of mine. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One may use lists of parameters for each kernel in conjunction with `$KernelID`. On each kernel, `$KernelID` simply evaluates on a number of the kernel. So all we have to do is to design the code in a way that it depends on `$KernelID`. In this case, we use `$KernelID` in order to index into the lists of parameters (indexing with `[[ ]]`, the short form of `Part`).

```
alist = {9, 8, 7, 6};
blist = {10, 20, 30, 40};
f[x_] := a x + b x

ParallelEvaluate[
 Block[{a = alist[[$KernelID]], b = blist[[$KernelID]]},
  f[1]
  ]
 ]
```

> {19, 28, 37, 46}

The drawback of this method is that the outcome depends on the number of kernels...

A better approach might be to use, e.g., `ParallelTable`. Here an example that hopefully illuminates what is going on:

```
f = {x, a, b} \[Function] a x + b x;
alist = {9, 8, 7, 6};
blist = {10, 20, 30, 40};

ParallelTable[
 Row[{"Kernel ", $KernelID, " computes ", i -> f[1, alist[[i]], alist[[i]]], "."}],
 {i, 1, Length[alist]}
 ]
```

> {Row[{"Kernel ", 4, " computes ", 1 -> 18, "."}],   Row[{"Kernel ", 3,
>   " computes ", 2 -> 16, "."}],   Row[{"Kernel ", 2, " computes ", 3 ->
>   14, "."}],   Row[{"Kernel ", 1, " computes ", 4 -> 12, "."}]}

A further, more functional oriented way could be `ParallelMap`:

```
ParallelMap[
 abpair \[Function] Row[{"Kernel ", $KernelID, " computes ",  f[1, abpair[[1]], abpair[[2]]], "."}],
 Transpose[{alist, blist}]
 ]
```

> {Row[{"Kernel ", 4, " computes ", 19, "."}],   Row[{"Kernel ", 3, "
>   computes ", 28, "."}],   Row[{"Kernel ", 2, " computes ", 37, "."}], Row[{"Kernel ", 1, " computes ", 46, "."}]}

Comment: Thank you very much. I get: `{2, 4}` as a result? Would you mind to comment your code? I don't understand the `[[$KernelID]]` part... how do you assign the function with different parameters to new kernels ? Thanks!

Comment: You obtain `{2,4}` because you have two kernels running (a processor with two cores), and `$KernelID` is the identification of each kernel...

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas I cannot go beyond that with my computer then ? ... I am asking because I can define a multitude of new kernels using "Evaluation" -> "Kernel Configuration Options"

Comment: I think not, although I am not an expert. As far I know, you can define the machine in which you can run your NoteBook. Then, for that machine you could use as many cores as it has. However, I am afraid no beyond...I mean, I think we cannot run the same NoteBook in many machines (each one with many cores)...Therefore, I cannot run my calculation at my home computer and at the same time in the one at my office...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you very much for your answer and your annotation. This is really helpful! :)

Comment: `abpair \[Function]` was not defined in your last example. But nice answer! +1

Comment: @henry Thanks! But I am not quite sure what you mean...

Comment: Never mind. I misread your last function. All works!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher why is not needed to use `DistributeDefinitions` for `f` in your code?

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Good question! I am not totally sure because I usually prefer vectorization and `Compile` for parallelization and use these facitlities only seldomly. IRC, `ParallelTable` and friends on older versions required you to use `DistributeDefinitions`. I once picked up that this was no longer needed because `ParallelTable` would do it automatically. But one should check performance: Maybe a callback to another kernel happens and slows down execution if we do not distribute the definitions  manually...

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Ah, the documention tells us that symbols in `$DistributedContexts` get distributed automatically. On a freshly started session with parallel kernels launched, `$DistributedContexts` contains ``Global``` already.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher understood, I appreciate your time... (+1)

Comment: Sorry to bother you, and thank you very much for this great detailed answer... but I still don't understand it. I can define a lot of new local kernels by going to "Evaluation" -> "Kernel Configuration Options" and creating new local kernels. Then I can run the same function in multiple notebooks, each with a different local kernel at the same time... I can run not only 2 local kernels but a multitude... which contradicts with the fact that I have only 2 cores..

Comment: @james "Kernel" does not mean "Core". The WolframKernels that you start manually are just simple processes that are managed by the operating system. Each of these kernels has his own scope, so definitions on different kernels do not interfer.Assigning notebooks to run a specific kernel shields it from events in other notebooks.

Comment: @james For parallelization it is the number of physical CPU cores that matters. By default, Mathematica starts only as many parallel kernels as there are _physical_ cores. (Even Intel would tell you that multithreading is not that useful for numerical computation.) You can also start more parallel kernels than there are cores but that won't speed up things. The managing overhead will rather slow down the execution.

Comment: @james Think of parallel kernels as truck drivers and cores as trucks. You won't get your cargo quicker to its destination by just hiring more and more drivers.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Ah, I see. This is a nice comparison. So even, if I hire a lot of new drivers, if I don't have enough trucks, most of the trucks will not move. Or in other words, if I create a multitude of different notebooks with all of them their own local kernel, the total computation time will never be faster than if I create only two of those notebooks and loop through them. Right ?

Comment: @james Right. In general, the best is to have as many parallel kernels as there are physical cores. Of course, very rule has its exceptions.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 6):

I guess that you begin to discover parallel computing with Mathematica by reading the tutorial
ParallelTools/tutorial/ParallelEvaluation.

That's the way I discovered it.

The problem is that the first instruction that this tutorial introduces is `ParallelEvaluate`.

It's misleading : `ParallelEvaluate` is seldom used and, when reading the tutorial, it takes time
to understand that it is not destinated to evaluate the same function with different parameters in parallel.

Fortunely there are many other instructions to do what you want.

Here are two solutions :

**Solution without risks, robust, conform to functional programming (recommended)**

```
f[{x_,a_,b_}]=a x + b x;
ParallelMap[f,{{1,1,1},{1,2,2},{1,3,3},{1,4,4}}]
```

> {2, 4, 6, 8}

It's prudent to verify that the computing was really done in parallel (as opposed to a premature evaluation of the whole expression in the main kernel) :

```
f[{x_,a_,b_}]=a x + b x;
ParallelMap["Kernel "<>ToString[$KernelID]<>" : "<>ToString[f[#]]&,
     {{1,1,1},{1,2,2},{1,3,3},{1,4,4}}]
```

> {"Kernel 4 : 2", "Kernel 3 : 4", "Kernel 2 : 6", "Kernel 1 : 8"}

**Other solution, more close to your code**

```
f[x_]=a x + b x;
DistributeDefinitions[a,b,f];
sub00=Table[ParallelSubmit[{params},(a=params[[1]];b=params[[2]];f[1])],
       {params,{{1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4}}}]
```

[image]

```
WaitAll[sub00]
```

[image]

> {2, 4, 6, 8}

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Would you mind pointing me or any other newbie to an instruction that will do the job?  Maybe with a small example? That would be very helpful for anyone trying to learn how to do it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looking forward seeing it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and nicely visualized answer ! +1 Can you tell me: 1. Why the first solution is better than the second ? 2. What does WaitAll do ? Thank you very much !

Comment: great answer +1